# JQuery appending '[object, Object]' rather than image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am using the `$.getJSON` function of JQuery to download the urls of some images and I am trying to output them inside a div. I am trying to get the output to look like this:

```
<a href="the image url (shot.short_url)"><img src="the direct image url (shot.image_teaser_url)" /></a>
```

However, it is outputting this instead:

```
<div id="body-wrapper">
    <a href="http://drbl.in/300896">[object Object]</a>
    <a href="http://drbl.in/298080">[object Object]</a>
    <a href="http://drbl.in/290395">[object Object]</a>
    <a href="http://drbl.in/290324">[object Object]</a>
    <a href="http://drbl.in/268595">[object Object]</a>
    <a href="http://drbl.in/265197">[object Object]</a>
    <a href="http://drbl.in/256368">[object Object]</a>
    <a href="http://drbl.in/252519">[object Object]</a>
    <a href="http://drbl.in/242235">[object Object]</a>
    <a href="http://drbl.in/241676">[object Object]</a>
</div>
```

Please can you tell me where I am going wrong in the case out outputting the image?

This is my code:

```
function work() {
            $('#body-wrapper').empty();
            $.getJSON("http://dribbble.com/jakekrehel/shots.json?callback=?", function(data){
                $.each(data.shots, function(i,shot){
                  var image = $('<img/>').attr('src', shot.image_teaser_url);
                  var title = '<a href=\"' + shot.short_url + '\">';
                  var string = title;
                  string = string + image;
                  string = string + '</a>';
                  $('#body-wrapper').append(string);
                });
              });
        }
```

Comment: It's an object not a string. Dereference it to the url value.

Comment: Thanks man, I'm using `var image = '<img src=\"' + shot.image_teaser_url + '\" />';` now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this within your `.each()` callback

```
// create image
var image = $('<img>').attr('src', shot.image_teaser_url);

// create anchor and append image
var anchor = $('<a>').attr('href', shot.short_url).append(image);

// append anchor to container
$('#body-wrapper').append(anchor);
```

Comment: I did `var image = '<img src=\"' + shot.image_teaser_url + '\" />';` instead, and it works perfectly.

Comment: @XcodeDev No, it doesn't. If the `image_teaser_url` or `short_url` strings contain any HTML characters, it could mess up your document or worse, introduce an XSS vulnerability. Use the appropriate DOM methods instead.

Answer (score 3):

image is a jQuery object and not a String - so appending it to a String will produce [object Object]

Ideally, change everything into an object - e.g.

```
$('#body-wrapper').append(
    $("<a/>",{"href": shot.short_url}).append(
    $("<img/>",{"src": shot.image_teaser_url}));
```

or cheat and do this
    string = string + image.html();

Either should work

Note: I typed those without syntax checking and there's a LOT of brackets, did my best tho!